# Inno Setup ComboBox how to store/access values

Tags: inno-setup

I am creating a custom InputQueryWizardPage with a ComboBox and trying to store values like so:

```
[Code]
var
//Define global variables
  InfoPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  ComboBox: TNewComboBox;
  strComboValue: String;

//Store the ComboBox string value
procedure ComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0:
    begin
      strComboValue := 'First Entry';
    end;
    1:
    begin
      strComboValue := 'Second Entry';
    end;
...
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  ComboLabel: TNewStaticText;
//Define the Equipment Information page
  InfoPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpSelectTasks,
    'Equipment Information', 'Please enter the equipment information?',
    'Please enter the equipment connected, then click Next.');
  InfoPage.Add('Location:', False);
  InfoPage.Add('Type:', False);
  ComboBox := TNewComboBox.Create(InfoPage);
  ComboBox.Parent := InfoPage.Surface;
  ComboBox.Top := InfoPage.Edits[1].Top + (InfoPage.Edits[1].Top - InfoPage.Edits[0].Top); 
  ComboBox.Width := (InfoPage.Edits[0].Width / 2) - ScaleX(10);
  ComboBox.Style := csDropDown;
  ComboBox.Items.Add('First Entry');
  ComboBox.Items.Add('Second Entry');
...
  ComboBox.OnChange := @ComboChange;
  ComboLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  ComboLabel.Caption := 'Equipment:';
  ComboLabel.Top := ComboBox.Top - ScaleY(16);
  ComboLabel.Parent := InfoPage.Surface;
end;
```

The trouble is that selecting the entry in the ComboBox does not store the values into the string so that I can call them later in the installation. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you are reading that he value before it's assigned. But in general, storing values this way is a very bad (but quite common) practice. For you it has no benefit. It can only lead to coding mistakes. If you are *caching* that value because of performance reasons, then I can tell you that it will *save* you almost nothing. It can be done differently. If you are reading that value, say, tens of times in a method, you can *cache* it in a local variable. If from tens of different methods, you can read it once from the combo box and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: What is the overall aim of this code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure ComboChange(Sender: TObject);
```

and

```
ComboBox.OnChange := @ComboChange;
```

are not required at all. To access the stored value from the ComboBox, simply read `ComboBox.Text`. Thanks @TLama.

Answer (score 0):

First ComboChange should be a TNotifyEvent. @ComboChange is a pointer. It shouldn't compile unless TNewComboBox redefines it as a pointer, which it doesn't having checked the inno help.

which may be why it's not working.

as pointer :) This (when it's an event):

```
procedure ComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case ComboBox.ItemIndex of
    0:
    begin
      strComboValue := 'First Entry';
    end;
    1:
    begin
      strComboValue := 'Second Entry';
    end;
...
  end;
end;
```

Is going to get extremely tedious.

All you need is:

```
procedure ComboChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  strComboValue := 'Whatever is default';
  if ComboBox.ItemIndex >= 0 then
    strComboValue := ComboBox.Items[ComboBox.ItemIndex];
end;
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong in that code (except a few typos). The `TNotifyEvent` signature is correct as well as its assignment.

Comment: To the final code, you could simply read `ComboBox.Text`, but it assumes that the OP wants to get the item text into that variable (which is not clear from the question at this time). About the method assignments, in Inno Setup Pascal Script you must use the `@` operator.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I needed, a way of accessing the string/text value of the ComboBox. I did not know that `ComboBox.Text` existed. I had tried `ComboBox.Value`, `Values` and `Value[1]` and since none of these worked, I figured I needed to write a procedure store the value into a string so I could access it in another procedure.